# what is the meaning of morpheus in portal level and skin level

Tags: portal, sakai

Can anyone explain the use of the Morpheus portal and skin in Sakai? What I mean to ask is, how do I enable those things and what are the differences to the neo skin and neo portal code in Sakai?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Morpheus (Mobile Optimized Responsive Portal for Higher Education Using Sass) is the new responsive design portal (the primary UI) which will be available in Sakai 11 (and is in a preview state for Sakai 10). The neo portal is the portal which was developed and released for Sakai 2.9. Before that the portal was known as the Charon portal.

If you want to test it you should really be using Sakai trunk (instead of 10.x). Either way, the following setting needs to be enabled in your sakai config file (typically sakai.properties). Make sure you check that they are not duplicated in the file.

```
portal.templates=morpheus
portal.neoprefix=
skin.default=morpheus-default
```

Also, if that doesn't work then check to make sure the morpheus dirs exist in the reference/library/src/webapp/skin directory. If they don't then you need to update to a newer version of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Morpheus is the new responsive design portal (the primary UI) which will be available in Sakai 11 (and is in a preview state for Sakai 10). The neo portal is the portal which was developed and released for Sakai 2.9. Before that the portal was known as the Charon portal.

Comment: Thank you Steve Swinsburg for providing a answer.

Comment: Thank you Steve Swinsburg for providing a answer. 
Actually I enabled this Morpheus portal and skin by giving following properties                  
portal.templates=morpheus
portal.neoprefix=
skin.default=morpheus-master
But here i am unable to see the exactly what are the changes while applying this portal and skin(I am using sakai10qa6).
I think might be I approach is wrong to enable the Morpheus  portal so can any one help me out how to enable the Morpheus portal.

Answer (score 1):

MORPHEUS=Mobile Optimized Responsive Portal for Higher Education Using Sass

Answer (score 1):

Here were some slides 
http://www.slideshare.net/alienresident/sakai-meet-morpheus-slides

And a presentation on this topic from Apereo 2014
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQyGgwUPeqU