# Sakai 11 default Logo Change

Tags: customization, sakai

I am using Sakai 11. i would like to know how to replace the  default sakai logo of serenity to a institution logo. what is the step/command to changing the default logo.

Answer (score 2):

If you've installing from the binary and you just want to change the logo it's going to be in your tomcat at webapps/library/skin/morpheus-default/images/logo.png. You can replace this file directly.

However if you want to do more customization on the logo more (like colors) you'll need to change the code in library updating the _defaults.scss and recompile.

In Sakai 11 this is in reference/library in the source, in Sakai 12 it's just in /library. From this directory look in /library/src/morpheus-master/sass/_defaults.scss

For more information on skin customization see 
[Morpheus 12 Documentation](https://github.com/sakaiproject/sakai/blob/master/library/) or [Morpheus 11 documentation](https://github.com/sakaiproject/sakai/tree/11.x/reference/) or [additional Morpheus information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034011/what-is-the-meaning-of-morpheus-in-portal-level-and-skin-level)

Comment: Isn't it rather library/skin/morpheus-default ?

Answer (score 0):

Logo here: tomcat.x.x.x/webapps/library/skin/morpheus-default/images/logo.png
You can replace your logo.